# Invalid cursor state - no current row when inserting row

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have tried researching this question and most of the time the answers are related to doing queries to collect data from a database. I am trying to insert data into the database and I keep getting this error:

> Invalid cursor state - no current row.

Here is my code:
It creates the database with no problems, but when I try to insert a row I get the error.

```
package importtimesheet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class ImportTimeSheet
{

    // JDBC driver name and database URL
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/PaperRoute";

    //  Database credentials
    static final String USER = "<username removed>";
    static final String PASS = "<password removed>";

    private static String buildit(String names, String types)
    {
        String[] na = names.split("\t");
        String[] ta = types.split("\t");
        String result = "CREATE TABLE HOURS_WORKED (";
        for (int i = 0; i < na.length; i++)
        {
            result = result + na[i] + " " + ta[i] + " not NULL,";
        }
        result = result + " PRIMARY KEY (DATE))";
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        boolean bon = false;
        String[] temp;
        String file_name = "C:\\Users\\Michael_2\\Dropbox\\Programming\\Finished         Programs\\ExportTimeSheet\\data.txt";
        String[] aryLines = new String[0];
        //IMPORT DATA FROM FLAT FILE
        try
        {
            ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
            aryLines = file.OpenFile();

    //            for (int i = 0; i < aryLines.length; i++)
    //            {
    //                System.out.println(aryLines[i]);
    //            }
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        String names = aryLines[0];
        String types = aryLines[1];

        //CREATE DB TABLE 
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs;

        try
        {
            //Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            //Open a connection
            System.out.println("Connecting to selected database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            System.out.println("Connected to database successfully...");

            //Execute a query
            System.out.println("Creating table in database...");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = buildit(names, types);
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("Created table in database...");
        } catch (SQLException se)
        {
            //Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally
        {
            //finally block used to close resources
            try
            {
                if (stmt != null)
                {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException se)
            {
            }// do nothing
            try
            {
                if (conn != null)
                {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException se)
            {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }//end finally try
        }//end try

        for (int i = 2; i < aryLines.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(aryLines[i]);
            temp = aryLines[i].split("\t");
            if (temp[1] == "BON")
            {
                bon = true;
            }
            try
            {
                String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/PaperRoute";
                String uName = "<username removed>";
                String uPass = "<password removed>";
                Connection con;
                Statement stmnt;
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName,uPass);
                stmnt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,     ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                String data = "SELECT * from HOURS_WORKED";
                rs = stmnt.executeQuery(data);

                Time arrived = java.sql.Time.valueOf(temp[2]);
                Time received = java.sql.Time.valueOf(temp[3]);
                Time left = java.sql.Time.valueOf(temp[4]);
                Time started = java.sql.Time.valueOf(temp[5]);
                Time finished = java.sql.Time.valueOf(temp[6]);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                java.util.Date parsed = sdf.parse(temp[0]);
                java.sql.Date sql = new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime());
                String[] na = names.split("\t");
                rs.moveToInsertRow();
                rs.updateDate(1, sql);
                rs.updateBoolean(2, bon);
                rs.updateTime(3, arrived);
                rs.updateTime(4, received);
                rs.updateTime(5, left);
                rs.updateTime(6, started);
                rs.updateTime(7, finished);
                rs.updateRow();
                System.out.println(sql);``
            } catch (ParseException pe)
            {
                System.out.println(pe.getMessage());
            } catch (SQLException se)
            {
                System.out.println(se.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the exception been thrown?

Comment: There isn't one. This is a clip of my output:
2014-06-11 WED 02:40:00 02:45:00 03:55:00 04:05:00 06:35:00
Invalid cursor state - no current row.
2014-06-12 THU 03:25:00 03:25:00 04:35:00 04:50:00 07:00:00
Invalid cursor state - no current row.
2014-06-13 FRI 02:25:00 02:30:00 03:45:00 04:00:00 06:40:00
Invalid cursor state - no current row.
2014-06-14 SAT 03:35:00 03:40:00 04:55:00 05:05:00 07:35:00
Invalid cursor state - no current row.
2014-06-15 SUN 02:50:00 03:00:00 04:30:00 04:45:00 07:30:00
Invalid cursor state - no current row.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)

Comment: I tried using System.out.println(" a line number") to narrow down where the problem was occuring. It seems to be the line rs.updateRow();

Comment: I'm an idiot, the exception message is Invalid cursor state - no current row. It's an SQLException.

Comment: don't be so harsh with yourself, this things happen all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you forgot something in your query,

```
String data = "SELECT * from HOURS_WORKED";
```

should be

```
String data = "SELECT * from HOURS_WORKED FOR UPDATE";
```

Comment: I've never seen this before and it seems to have no effect. I'll keep it in mind though. It might be part of the puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out that the reason I've been getting this error is that I had rs.updateRow(); where I should have had rs.insertRow();
Now that I have made the correction (along with other changes mentioned above) I'm not getting an error any more, but the database is not being updated. But I guess that is a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this works at all; you are registering a mysql driver but using a derby url.

```
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/PaperRoute";
```

Perhaps you want (for a derby database):

```
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/PaperRoute";
```

or (for mysql database):

```
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:1527/PaperRoute";
```

Depending on the database you are using.

There are also various places where you 'hardcode' the values instead of using these constants.

Comment: I think this is where I went wrong. I was trying to mash together instructions from two different websites on how to use databases. I am trying to use the database in NetBeans. I noticed one was using derby and the other mysql, but not really understanding the difference I just tried to get something together.

Comment: I cleaned up my code a bit. I made a method to connect so it's in one place
private static Connection connect()
        {
            String user = "<username removed>";
            String password = "<password removed>";
            String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
            String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/PaperRoute";
            Connection con = null;
            try{
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            }catch(SQLException s)
            {
            }
            return con;
        }

Comment: It turns out that what I wanted was a JAR file. Thanks for helping me see that I needed to look into this.